# using extjs when json is dynamically passed pie-chart is not drawn

Tags: json, jsp, extjs, struts2, pie-chart

I've drawn the pie-chart successfully when i directly pass the data like as shown below

```
data:  [{
            'name': 'metric one',
            'data': 10
        }, {
            'name': 'metric two',
            'data': 7
        }, {
            'name': 'metric three',
            'data': 5
        }, {
            'name': 'metric four',
            'data': 2
        }, {
            'name': 'metric five',
            'data': 27
        }]
    });
```

but when i tried to bring those json datas through ajax i'm not getting the pie-chart.
can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Ext.chart.series.Pie Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/try/extjs/4.1.0/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css"/>
    <script src="http://cdn.sencha.io/try/extjs/4.1.0/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script src="extJS/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="myExample"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'getJsonforPie.action',
        dataType : "json",
        params: {

        },
        success: function(response){
            getResources = response.responseText;
           alert(JSON.stringify(getResources))

        }
    });

    // var store = Ext.create('myStore');
    //to load data use store.load()

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: ['name', 'data'],
        data: getResources
          //  [{

//            'name': 'metric one',
//            'data': 10
//        }, {
//            'name': 'metric two',
//            'data': 7
//        }, {
//            'name': 'metric three',
//            'data': 5
//        }, {
//            'name': 'metric four',
//            'data': 2
//        }, {
//            'name': 'metric five',
//            'data': 27
//        }]
    });


    Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: 'myExample',
        width: 500,
        height: 350,

        animate: true,
        store: store,
        theme: 'Base:gradients',
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            angleField: 'data',

            showInLegend: true,
            tips: {
                trackMouse: true,
                width: 140,
                height: 28,

                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    // calculate and display percentage on hover
                    var total = 0;
                    store.each(function(rec) {
                        total += rec.get('data');
                    });
                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + Math.round(storeItem.get('data') / total * 100) + '%');
                }
            },
            highlight: {
                segment: {
                    margin: 20
                }
            },
            label: {
                field: 'name',
                display: 'rotate',
                contrast: true,
                font: '18px Arial'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="getJsonforPie" class="commonpackage.DashboardUtilities" method="getJsonforPie"/>
```

**getJsonforPie method**

```
public void getJsonforPie() throws IOException
{
        HttpServletResponse response= (HttpServletResponse)  
        ActionContext.getContext().get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);
        JSONArray zoneAreas = new JSONArray();
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
         HashMap map=new HashMap();
         map.put("name", "metric "+i);
         map.put("data", 10); 
         zoneAreas.put(map);
        }
        System.out.println(zoneAreas.toString());
        response.getWriter().write(zoneAreas.toString());
}
```

***UPDATE 2**  (**app.js**)*

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var getResources;
    var flag=0;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'getJsonforPie.action',
        dataType : "json",
        params: {

        },
        success: function(response){
        getResources = response.responseText;
        createChart(getResources);

}
    });

var createChart = function(resources) {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
       fields: ['name', 'data'],
       data: resources
    });


    Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: 'myExample',
        width: 500,
        height: 350,

        animate: true,
        store: store,
        theme: 'Base:gradients',
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            angleField: 'data',

            showInLegend: true,
            tips: {
                trackMouse: true,
                width: 140,
                height: 28,

                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    var total = 0;
                    store.each(function(rec) {
                        total += rec.get('data');
                    });
                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + Math.round(storeItem.get('data') / total * 100) + '%');
                }
            },
            highlight: {
                segment: {
                    margin: 20
                }
            },
            label: {
                field: 'name',
                display: 'rotate',
                contrast: true,
                font: '18px Arial'
            }
        }]
    });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getResource` variable is visible only inside the `success` function

Move the code that you are using to create the chart to some function and call it inside the `success` function, it will be something like this:

```
var createChart = function(resources) {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
       fields: ['name', 'data'],
       data: resources
    });


    Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: 'myExample',
        width: 500,
        height: 350,
        animate: true,
        store: store,
        theme: 'Base:gradients',
        series: [{ ....
        .....
        .....
        .....
      });
    });
}
```

And then call it inside your `success` function

```
success: function(response){
   getResources = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
   createChart(getResources);
   alert(JSON.stringify(getResources));
}
```

Comment: Sir still its not working.........i did exactly what you have said.......see my update 2

Comment: Are you sure that data are sent back from the server, does it print any thing when you do `alert(JSON.stringify(getResources))`?

Comment: "[{\"name\":\"metric 1\",\"data\":10},{\"name\":\"metric 2\",\"data\":10},{\"name\":\"metric 3\",\"data\":10},{\"name\":\"metric 4\",\"data\":10}]"................this is the json printing in the alert

Comment: sir can you please tell me why pie-chart is not drawn

Comment: sir is there any problem wth the json

Comment: No, there is nothing with your JSON, try to debug `createChart` method using `firebug` or chrome developer tools. check if the data are sent to it correctly

Comment: sir if i place this like this..... data: [{'name':'metric 1','data':10},{'name':'metric 2','data':10},{'name':'metric 3','data':10},{'name':'metric 4','data':10}]...................instead of  ......data: resources..........i'm getting the pie-chart

Comment: In the `createChart` method, what is the result of `alert(JSON.stringify(resources))` ?

Comment: this is the result for alert(JSON.stringify(resources))..............{"request":{"id":1,"headers":{"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"},"options":{"dataType":"json","url":"getJsonforPie.action","params":{}},"async":true},"requestId":1,"status":200,"statusText":"OK","responseText":"[{\"name\":\"metric 1\",\"data\":10},{\"name\":\"metric 2\",\"data\":10},{\"name\":\"metric 3\",\"data\":10},{\"name\":\"metric 4\",\"data\":10}]","responseXML":null}